# jQuery UI autocomplete, always show a row on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using [jquery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). I want to show last row "Didn't find? Add New" when element is focused. It should be shown always at bottom. It is replacement for "No result found" message. However, no result found message only appear when there is no result, I want to show this row when there are results and when there is no result.

[image]

I tried

```
response: function (event, ui) {
                        if (!ui.content.length) {
                            var noResult = {value: "#", label: "No results found"};
                            ui.content.push(noResult);
                            //$("#message").empty();
                        } else {
                            $("#message").empty();
                        }
                    }
```

But it is not solving the purpose as it only shows while there is no result and by default appends "View" link, which I don't want at that row.

To render last row I used

```
open: function (event, ui) {
                        $('.ui-autocomplete').append('<li class="ui-menu-item add-new">Didn\'t find? <a href="javascript:alert(\'redirecting...\')">Add New</a></li>'); //See all results
                        //$("ui-autocomplete-input").css("border-radius", 0);
                    }
```

It shows when there are results, but get hide when there are no results to show.
I am looking for the solution which can help me show it in both condition and at bottom of other results.

Thanks!

Comment: you can add the link weather you get result of not so you will always have that option shown.

Comment: sorry, not understood your comment. Please elaborate it or put it as an answer.